# Getting error QB -sdk NAME must be unique

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the IPPDotNetDevKit.2.1.12.0 SDK to first get a list of all customers.  I then add new customers which works 99.9 percent of the time, but for some (and thereafter persistant for that perticular entity) I am getting this error;

QB -sdk NAME must be unique in QB! name = ABC Company

I don't see the customer in QuickBooks (so sync error), and I look at the set of customers returned in the 1st request (where I set qb_query.ActiveOnly = false)

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomerQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <StartPage>1</StartPage>
    <ChunkSize>500</ChunkSize>
</CustomerQuery>
```

and the customer in question "ABC Company" is clearly not there (only have 43 customers returned so ChukSize is not the issue).  So it seems I tired to add that customer, it got "stuck", and now everytime I try to add it again, I get "name must be unique". However checking sync errors;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomerQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <StartPage>1</StartPage>
    <ChunkSize>100</ChunkSize>
</CustomerQuery>
```

I get no rows returned. (it does look a little funny where the SDK puts ErroredObjectsOnly but what do I know).

So my question is, how can I get either the customer query or the sync error query to return the "lost" customer so I can find the ID and delete it or fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Names have to be unique across all Customers, Vendors, Employees, and "Other Name" elements.

Did you also check to make sure that there's no Vendor, Employee, or "Other Name" with that same name?